# how to assign 3 different colour to rows in an order and reverse that order

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, user-interface

I am designing an app where I am using the table view. Here I have to assign 3 different colours to the cell of tableview simultaneously... Here comes the problem after assigning these colours from the very next row I have to again assign the same colours in reverse order. For Example I have 3 colours the sequence in which I need to assign these colours is :
Red - Green - Blue - Blue - Green - Red - Red - Green - Blue - Blue - Green - Red... and so on.
here lets say we don't know how many rows are there this sequence should go on like this only... Please help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Declare below array as global array :

```
 NSMutableArray *colorArray;
```

`ViewDidLoad` function :

```
 colorArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIColor redColor],[UIColor greenColor],[UIColor blueColor],[UIColor blueColor], [UIColor greenColor], [UIColor redColor], nil];
```

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` method :

```
cell.backgroundColor = [colorArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row % 5];
```

And done :).

Answer (score 0):

U need to initialise an array of colors and use in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method
Declare an array

```
NSMutableArray *colors;
```

in did load

```
color=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

call this method in viewDidLoad

```
-(void)initializeColorArray
{
UIColor *color1=[UIColor redColor];
UIColor *color2=[UIColor orangeColor];
UIColor *color3=[UIColor yellowColor];
NSArray *Listcolor = @[color1,color2,color3,color3,color2,color1];
for (int i=0; i<[tableData count]; i=i+[Listcolor count])
{
    for (int i=0; i<[Listcolor count]; i++)
    {
        [colors addObject:[Listcolor objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}
NSLog(@"%@",color);
}
```

and use color array to assign background color in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method

```
cell.backgroundColor=[colors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

It would give same output as you require
Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: This would do, but not the best way. Whenever you add/remove something in the tableview datasource you have to add/remove from the color array as well. And also, you only have to show 3 colors only. @sneha's answer is the right way.

Comment: if u require same color pattern (i.e. Red - Green - Blue - Blue - Green - Red - Red - Green - Blue - Blue - Green - Red... )  irrespective of table view's datasource.. my code would work. I agree sneha's code is fine but doesnt gives required output . output of sneha's code is like Red - Green - Blue - Blue - Green - Red - Green - Blue - Blue - Green - Red.. unlike the required one.

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple But Tricky Question

just paste this in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
 cell.backgroundColor=[self colorForIndex];
```

and define method

```
-(UIColor*)colorForIndex
{


UIColor *returnColor;
NSArray *colorsArray=@[[UIColor whiteColor],[UIColor redColor],[UIColor greenColor]];
NSArray *reverseColorsArray=@[[UIColor greenColor],[UIColor redColor],[UIColor whiteColor]];

if(currentSet%2==0){

    returnColor =[colorsArray objectAtIndex:counter3];

}else{

    returnColor =[reverseColorsArray objectAtIndex:counter3];

}
counter3++;
if(counter3==3){

    currentSet++;
    counter3=0;
}

return returnColor;
```

}

Comment: try this and let me know